# OleDbConnectionStringBuilder.sConnection' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledbconnection

I am trying to connect to my database, and this is what I have typed:

```
string sConnection; 
sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=Cars.accdb;";
```

but, the error message it gives me is: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

as well as: Error '...OleDbConnectionStringBuilder.sConnection' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

I did use these using statements as well:

```
using System.Data.OleDb; 
using System.Data;

using System.Object;
using System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder; 
using System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder;

namespace FinalProject
{
    class DataAccessLayer
    {
        public sealed class OleDbConnectionStringBuilder : DataAccessLayer
        {


            public OleDbCommand dbCmd; //Command object
            public OleDbDataReader dbReader; //Data Reader object

            string sConnection;
            sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                               "Data Source=Cars.accdb;";
```

Can you help me figure out why I am receiving these errors?

Comment: Can you post more code? Which line is this error in?

Comment: where is your `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder`?

Comment: Can you edit the question and put the code there?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare the value for a class variable this way. Change it to

```
string sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                           "Data Source=Cars.accdb;";
```

The line `sConnection = "...";` is valid only within a method, property, etc.

Comment: What method, property, etc. would you suggest that I have it in?

Comment: The only other place that it makes sense to set a default field value for a class is in its constructor.